# mojimojiモジュールがimportできない

Tags: python

mojimojiモジュールがインストールはできるのですが、importができません。

`pip install mojimoji`はうまくいきます。
確認しても、

```
pip install mojimoji
Requirement already satisfied: mojimoji in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.0.11)
```

のようになります。ですが、

```
import mojimoji
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
```

となってしまいます。

https://qiita.com/Mopepe51/items/a28616356a85abcf6d99
を参考に、

```
pip install "numpy-1.19.1+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
```

を試しましたが、変わりません。

Anacondaが入っているPCでもそうでないPCでも変わりません。

**実行環境**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問のとおり、Python の 3.7.7 と 3.6.8 では問題の状況が再現しました。

ただし 3.8.5 ではimport出来てメソッド呼び出しも正常に動作します。

いずれも `pip`, `setuptools`, `wheel` だけ(最新版を)インストールした状態で確認しました。

最近上記のモジュール(wheelでさえも)が割と頻繁に更新されているので、何かしら影響があったのかもしれません。

以下のような対応が考えられます。

- Python 3.8.5環境に移行する
- Python 3.7.x環境で、実際に何のDLLがロード出来なくてエラーになっているのか調べて対処する
- Python 3.7.x環境で、各種モジュールの版数を段々と昔に戻してみて動作するか試してみる